# JSOUP parsing a table for form fields and labels

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to use JSOUP to parse a form with fields inside of a table in order to get the fields and their labels. The problem I am running into is I cannot find any pattern or common attributes to the labels. Below is an example of the HTML pages with labels marked as Label 1, Label 2, etc, and fields as field_1, field_2, etc.

```
<form id="some_form" method="post" action="some_page.do">
    <div class="main_div">
        <table id="main_table" class="table_class">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10" align="center" class="pad_bottom pad_top">
                    Label 1: 
                    <input type="text" name="field_1" value="Field 1 value" id="field_1"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10" align="center">
                    Label 2:
                    <span class="radio_class"><input type="radio" name="field_2" value="No" checked="checked" class="radio_field" id="field_2"/> No</span>
                    <span class="radio_class"><input type="radio" name="field_2" value="Yes" class="radio_field" id="field_2"/> Yes</span><br/>
                    <span class="extra">Some text to ignore</span>
                    More text to ignore
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10" align="center">
                    <table width="90%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td_class">
                                Some text to ignore
                            </td>
                            <td class="td_class">
                                Some text to ignore
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align=3"left" class="another_td_class">                    
                                Label 3<br/>
                                More text for label 3
                            </td>                     
                            <td align="left" class="another_td_class">      
                                <input type="hidden" name="field_3_hidden" value="1" id="field_3"/>
                                <span class="radio_class"><input type="radio" name="field_3" value="1" id="field_3"/>1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1<br/>
                                <span class="radio_class"><input type="radio" name="field_3" value="2" checked="checked" onfocus="" id="field_3"/> 2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 2<br/>
                               <br/>                          
                            </td>                      
                        <tr>
                        <tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="heading" colspan="2" width="50%">Label 4</td>
                <td class="heading" width="50%">Label 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" class="td_class nowrap">
                    <input type="integer" name="field_4a" maxlength="2" size="2" value="42" class="integer_class" id="field_4"/>
                    Additional text for label 4
                    <br/>
                    <span class="span_class">Text to ignore</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td_class nowrap">
                    <input type="radio" name="field_4b" value="A" class="radio_class" id="field_4b"/>A<br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="field_4b" value="B" checked="checked" class="radio_class" id="field_4b"/>B
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <td align="center" class="td_class nowrap">
                    <input type="radio" name="field_5" value="C" checked="checked" class="radio_class" id="field_5"/>C
                    <input type="radio" name="field_5" value="D" class="radio_class" id="field_5"/>D
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

The closest I have come is with the below code, however with the labels often being in different places, and sometimes having extra text I'm still having issues.

```
Set<MyElement> myElements = new HashSet<MyElement>();
Element mainDiv = page.select("div.main_div").first();
if (mainDiv != null) {
    Elements children = mainDiv.children();
    Elements tds = children.select("td");
    for (Element td : tds) {
        Elements inputs = td.select("input");
        for (Element input : inputs) {
            String field = input.id();
            if (field != null && !field.isEmpty()) {
                String label = td.text();
                MyElement myElement = new MyElement(field, label);
                myElements.add(myElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without there being any pattern or common attributes to the labels I'm thinking what I want to do isn't possible, but this is my first time using JSOUP so I'm hoping there is something I don't know about that will let me do this.

Comment: Can you post what the expected output would be based off of the sample HTML? It's difficult to tell what all needs to be selected based off of just the sample.

Comment: I updated the Java part of the code above to hopefully help. I'm trying to match the field and label together and put them in a custom class. I want to end up with: ["field_1", "Label 1"], ["field_2", "Label 2"], ["field_3", "Label 3"], ["field_4", "Label 4"], ["field_5", "Label 5"]. For each input I want to group the input name with it's "label". The issue I'm having is the label isn't always in the same place of the HTML, isn't identified as a label, and sometimes there is extra text inside the tag the label is in that isn't part of the label ("text to ignore" in the example above).

Comment: That makes it a little more clear. So what would you expect with the input fields like 'field_4b' would they be ignored or paired with 'Label 4'?

Comment: They can be ignored. I only need one of the field_4x fields matched with Label 4. However if I ended up with all of them matched I could deal with that no problem also.

Comment: Ok and do they literally match up by number or is that just dummy data? I.e. will it always be Label 1 matches field 1 ... where the value '1' is what links them up.

Comment: They do not always match, and frequently the label contains extra words. My first thought was to do something like an idexOf to see if the words from the field are in the label, but I found cases where the labels don't contain any words from the field.

Comment: Sounds like there is nothing that actually matches them up? If you took away the numbers what would tell you that you had the right Labels paired with the right inputs? It certainly doesn't seem like the HTML is logically laid out either that you could pair by table rows or anything...

Comment: When you visually look at the rendered form in the browser you can make sense of what goes together only because people look at forms all the time and have an intuitive sense of how they are laid out if that makes sense. When I look at the HTML alone I see no logical layout to it.

Comment: Without something to clearly match up the labels and inputs or at least a structure of the html that would consistently show which ones belonged together I'm not sure there's a way to select them all and match them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way ... this looks like a good start to making sense of the labels.

The rough system matching a label from a field so far is:

1. Text earlier in this `<td>` cell
2. Text in the previous `<td>` cell on the row
3. Text in the `<td>` cell in the column above

To do this, involves walking around the `<table>` figuring out what text is in each cell and storing these by (row,cell), to come back to from the fields.  Where there is a `colspan` value, clearly that counts as multiple cells.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class TableParser {
    private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> cells = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    private void parseTable(Element table) {
        int rowNum = 0;
        for (Element row : table.select("> tbody > tr")) {
            parseRow(rowNum++, row);
        }
    }

    private void parseRow(int rowNum, Element row) {
        int columnNum = 0;
        for (Element cell : row.select("> td")) {
            String colspanText = cell.attr("colspan");
            int colspan = 1;
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(colspanText))
                colspan = Integer.parseInt(colspanText);

            addCell(rowNum, columnNum, colspan, cell);
            parseCell(rowNum, columnNum, cell);

            columnNum += colspan;
        }
    }

    private void addCell(int rowNum, int columnNum, int colspan, Element cell) {
        Map<Integer, String> rowCells = cells.computeIfAbsent(rowNum,
                r -> new LinkedHashMap<>());
        for (int i = 0; i < colspan; i++)
            rowCells.put(columnNum + i, labelIn(cell));
    }

    private String labelIn(Element cell) {
        return cell.textNodes().get(0).text().trim();
    }

    private String cellAt(int rowNum, int columnNum) {
        Map<Integer, String> rowCells = cells.get(rowNum);
        if (rowCells == null)
            return null;
        return rowCells.get(columnNum);
    }

    private void parseCell(int rowNum, int columnNum, Element cell) {
        // Don't drill down into the nested table yet
        if (!cell.select("table").isEmpty())
            return;
        for (Element input : cell.select("input")) {
            String label = labelIn(cell);
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(label))
                label = cellAt(rowNum, columnNum - 1);
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(label))
                label = cellAt(rowNum - 1, columnNum);
            System.out.println(String.format("%s->%s at (%d,%d)", label,
                    input.attr("name"), rowNum, columnNum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new java.io.File("/temp/labels.html"),
                java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
            new TableParser().parseTable(table);
        }
    }
}
```

More to do to combine labels etc, and maybe read a bit more text in each cell, but this was the result so far:

```
Label 1:->field_1 at (0,0)
Label 2:->field_2 at (1,0)
Label 2:->field_2 at (1,0)
Label 4->field_4a at (4,0)
Label 4->field_4b at (4,1)
Label 4->field_4b at (4,1)
Label 5->field_5 at (4,2)
Label 5->field_5 at (4,2)
Label 3->field_3_hidden at (1,1)
Label 3->field_3 at (1,1)
Label 3->field_3 at (1,1)
```

Comment: I'm running through testing this on different pages, and it's looking promising so far!

Answer (score 0):

I see a few patterns here. You say you want to get the fields and their labels.  Let's think about this a bit differently.  Here is what I see.

1. All the elements you care about are input elements.
2. All input elements have an associated label
3. The label name is the value of the input element need attribute
4. Some input elements have the same name which means they are associated with the same label.

Given these observations can you simply parse all the input fields and group then my name (same name, same group).  Since you know the value of the name attribute for all input elements corresponds with it's respective label you don't even need to look for the label.

Your question was about patterns not the code behind it. If you think this answer will work try to code it. If you need help coding it let me know. I have a project that uses JSOUP and I'd we be willing to write a PoC as long as you provide sample HTML to parse (preferably more than you already posted)

Comment: 1. Yes, what I care about are the inputs
2. Correct
3. I tried to take this approach but ran into issues. For example the input ID may be "status" and the associated label could be "What is the status?" so they don't exactly match.
4. Yes, this is correct

<ol>I wish I could give you actual values from the page, but the information on the html page is all confidential so I'm not able to post the actual HTML page or the real values used.

Comment: If you want to substitute the confidential htnl with lorem ipsum of the same format I'm willing to help, but you can't expect anyone to find a pattern without an accurate sample

Comment: Actually what I already posted is an exact copy of the HTML only with the confidential information changed. So if you replace Label 1 and field_1 with lorem lipsum that would be the only difference.